# How to return an subset of Array of characters?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to dynamically chop an array of letters but I can't seem to reconvert the result back into a [String]

```
let letters:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
let lettersarray = Array(letters.characters)

var targetNum = 14 // Show just the first 14 characters

var resultsArray = [String]()

let resultsSlice = lettersarray.dropLast(lettersarray.count - targetNum) // Returns an Array Slice instead of an Array

let newresultsArray = Array(resultsSlice) // Returns Array<_element> instead of [String]
```

How do I return a [String] ie ["a","b","c"... eg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the `Character` array back to `String`

```
let resultsArray = lettersarray.dropLast(lettersarray.count - targetNum).map{String($0)}
```

alternatively (credits to Leo Dabus)

```
let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
let targetNum = 14
let resultsArray = letters.characters.prefix(targetNum).map{String($0)}
```

Comment: `lettersarray.prefix(targetNum).map{String($0)}`

Comment: @LeoDabus very nifty :-)

Comment: Why do we need to remap?

Comment: Because `Character` cannot be casted to `String`

Answer (score 2):

No need for an array here. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but if you just want the first 14 characters of a string, use the `prefix` method:

```
    let s = String("abcdefghijklmno".characters.prefix(14))
```

Comment: I was actually after it as a string array - but that is a good solution as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting a `String` and want an array of characters which is a slice of characters from that `String`, you could use Swift's Half-Open Range Operator found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html).

```
let letters:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
let lettersArray = Array(letters.characters)
let targetNum = 2
let resultsArray = lettersArray[0..<targetNum]
```

This will give you an `ArraySlice<Character>`. If you want an `Array<Character>` you could do this:

```
let resultsArray:Array<Character> = Array(lettersArray[0..<targetNum]) // ["a","b"]
```

Comment: this will result an arraySlice of characters `ArraySlice<Character>`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for pointing this out! I edited the answer accordingly.