# Returning groups from array in swift 4.2

Tags: swift

I've seen this SO question ([How to return an subset of Array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956769/how-to-return-an-subset-of-array-of-characters)) but the problem is it is only dealing with a one-off return of the first characters of a string.

I'm trying to achieve something different but am not sufficiently familiar with the Swift language to know what functionality I need.

My problem is as follows, I've got an array:

`["10", "44", "33", "31", "38", "49", "8", "4", "40"]`

What would be the "Swift 4.2" way to return, for example, groups of three, i.e. :

```
["10", "44", "33"]
["31", "38", "49"]
["8", "4", "40"]
```

Also bear in mind the array may not always be exactly divisible (e.g. the above example array could easily have 10 values not 9) , so I would need to ignore any "excess" numbers at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` on array created by using `stride`. As `to` pass last index of item in `array` which can be divisible by three without the rest (excess numbers will be ignored). Now inside `map` closure return array of elements with indexes `$0`...`$0+2`

```
let array = ["10", "44", "33", "31", "38", "49", "8", "4", "40"]
let finalArray = stride(from: 0, to: array.endIndex - (array.endIndex % 3), by: 3).map {
    Array(array[$0...$0+2])
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I just discovered the stride function but I didn't make the connection to being able to use it for this application.  Thanks !!!

Comment: Doesn't work for arrays with a count that is not a multiple of 3. This question is a duplicate. have a look at matt's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856224/2907715)

Comment: @Carpsen90 I noticed, but your comment was written earlier

Comment: Don't you think this a duplicate question? and a better answer is given there? Answering duplicates [is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). Anyway, you could make your solution shorter `finalArray.append(Array(array[n...min(n+2, array.count - 1)]))`. There are other improvements that would make it faster...

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes I agree, it's similar but; from OP's question: *...so I would need to ignore any "excess" numbers at the end of the array*

Comment: this checks unnecessarily every iteration the array count property. It would be much easier to remove the guard, change the result to ArraySlice and use a range like `$0..<min($0+3,array.endIndex)`

Comment: `let final = stride(from: 0, to: array.endIndex, by: 3).map {
        array[$0..<min($0+3, array.endIndex)]
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus with using `map` I agree. Anyway if they should be less than three items in last array, he wants to ignore these items

Comment: Just drop the excess if needed using `array.dropLast(array.endIndex % 3)`

Comment: `let array = ["10", "44", "33", "31", "38", "49", "8", "4", "40","1"]
let trimmed = array.dropLast(array.endIndex % 3)
let final = stride(from: 0, to: trimmed.endIndex, by: 3).map {
        Array(trimmed[$0..<$0+3])
}
print(final)`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, I wrote a solution, a just need to rewrite answer

Comment: @LeoDabus btw thank you!